# The popup bar isn't shown any more in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I accindentally clicked on "Diese Nachricht nicht mehr einblenden, wenn Popups blockiert wurden"- I don't know the exact english text, but I tried to get the popup information bar back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this version, there is no "standard" menu item to set this back, so You have to type `about:config` in address bar, accept the warning and search for:
`privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage` and set back to "true" (which is standard).

See also: [Support Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/829652)